# Find 2 heavy fakes among 11 coins on a 3-pan balance

Tags: weighing

I give you **11 coins**, which look exactly the same. Among them are **two fake coins**. All genuine coins weigh the same. The fake coins are a little **heavier** than the genuine ones, and they may have a different weight from each other. You cannot distinguish their weight by hand.

You have no own utility to weigh coins, so I suggest you use my [three-pan balance](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15988/a-balance-with-three-pans-detecting-the-lightest-pan-find-the-one-lighter-ball) which, upon activation, lifts the unique pan with the lightest load. If there is no unique lightest pan, none of the pans will rise. You may only weigh the coins I gave you. Moreover, you are only allowed to perform **three weighings**.

As you may remember from [a previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16006/a-balance-with-three-pans-detecting-the-lightest-pan-find-the-two-heavier-ball), under these conditions, the two fake coins can not always be identified.

To help you, and for my amusement, I give you **one additional genuine coin**, which looks and weighs the same as the other genuine coins, and which you may use in your weighings to come.

Can you identify the two fake coins under these circumstances? If so, how?

Comment: I'd say it's not possible, but if you need one... well... Question: Can several coins be put in a pan at the same time?

Comment: Can we assume the weight difference is less than half the weight of a real coin?

Comment: @the4seasons Questions like these always allow you to put several coins in the pan at the same time.

Comment: If I'm correct here, you have 64 possible outcomes, which you want to map to 55 results.

Comment: How does the scale behave if two pans share the same weight and are both lighter than the third?

Comment: @PrincessTrevor _If there is no unique lightest pan, none of the pans will rise._ This line is enough to explain what would happen.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Looked right over that, mb.

Comment: @frodoskywalker For this question, you may assume that the two heavy fakes are each lighter than 3/2 of a genuine coin. But I doubt that this restriction is of any use for this question, mainly because most weighings will require an even distribution of coins. I have not yet seen a variant of this puzzle where it makes any difference, i.e. any problem solvable with this restriction is also solvable without it.

Comment: @Christian agreed. I thought I had a method that worked with an uneven distribution. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

Label the coins A-L, with **L** being the known genuine coin.

Weigh ABCD *vs* EFGH *vs* IJKL.

If no pan rises, then both heavy coins are on the same pan.
There are ${4\choose 2} = 6$ combinations where both heavy coins are on Pan 1, and 6 combinations where both are on Pan 2, but only ${3\choose 2} = 3$ combinations were both are on Pan 3, since we know coin L is genuine.  That adds up to 15 possibilities.

If Pan 3 rises, then one heavy coin is on Pan 1 and another on Pan 2, for a total of $4\times 4 = 16$ combinations.  If Pan 2 rises, then there are only $12$ combinations, again because we know coin L is genuine.  Likewise for Pan 1.

**If no pan rose on the first weighing**, then the second weighing should be  ABEF *vs* CGIJ *vs* DHKL.  The results of this would be:

- None: AB, EF, IJ
- Pan 1: CD, GH, IK, JK
- Pan 2: AD, BD, EH, FH
- Pan 3: AC, BC, EG, FG

In the first case, for the third weighing, use AE *vs* BI *vs* EJ.  The two heavy coins are now split and one of the three pans will rise.

In the other three cases, there are four patterns of which at least two intersect by one coin.  Put the intersecting coin on Pan 1, and each of the others from the pairings on Pans 2 & 3.  Pick one other pattern and split its coins between Pans 2 & 3.  Put other coins aside and fill in with known genuine coins (of which you have several).

For example, if Pan 1 rose, you would weigh KA *vs* IC *vs* JD.  If the pattern was GH, then no Pan would rise.  CD would raise Pan 1, IK would raise Pan 3, and JK would raise Pan 2.

**If Pan 3 rose on the first weighing**, then one of the heavy coins is in ABCD, and the other in EFGH, for a total of $16$ possibilities.  Coins I,J,K, & L are now all known to be genuine.

Weigh ABGH *vs* CDIJ *vs* EFKL.

- No Pan: AG, AH, BG, BH
- Pan 1: CE, CF, DE, DF
- Pan 2: AE, AF, BE, BF
- Pan 3: CG, CH, DG, DH

In all four of these cases, you have four patterns where one coin is from one pair and the other coin from the other pair.  The weighing pattern for this is similar to above, but requiring 2 genuine coins.

No Pan: weigh AI *vs* BG *vs* HJ.

AG would raise Pan 3; AH would raise Pan 2; BG  would raise no pan, and BH would raise Pan 1.

A similar pattern would work for any of the results of the second weighing.

**If Pan 1 or 2 rose on the first weighing**, follow the same logic for Pan 3 rising, with the different sets of coins.  Any of the possibilities where coin L came out heavy would obviously not happen, but otherwise the logic would be the same.

**QED**